# Joomla 2.5 Mijoshop Redirect Loop

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, redirect-loop

The issue i'm encountering is as follows: When the Joomla backend is logged into, there's no problems, however upon going to Extend->MijoShop->Dashboard a redirect loop is thrown. At this point if you refresh the page it allows you through to the dashboard, and the redirect loop won't be thrown again for that browser session.

Based on some research I was attempting to force non-www to www and www to non-www with poor results in the .htacess file.  A nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. No other parts of the site are presenting loops.

Answer (score 0):

Seem that something is wrong with your .htaccess file. Please try to put the default joomla .htaccess and use this rule for the non www to www redirection:

Force the www.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^your-site.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.your-site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Remove the www.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^your-site.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://your-site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

[full tutorial could be found here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/www-no-www/)